# how to save the facebook password/access token for login

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I want to create an application that will login me with facebook eachtime with out asking username and password. How I can store the facebook password or access token to login

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook get access Token](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5088676/facebook-get-access-token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ to discover how to authenticate, get a token then you can use it in your app to access the Graph API.

Note that tokens can only last up to 60 days.